# AttributeError: 'Robot' object has no attribute 'introduce_self'

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm a beginner in class & objects and was wondering why the line r2.introduce_self had an attribute error with an object that doesn't have an attribute.

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, rname, rcolor, rweight):
        self.name = rname
        self.color = rcolor
        self.weight = rweight


def introduce_self(self):
    print("my name is " + self.name)


r1 = Robot("Tom", "Red", 30)
r2 = Robot("Jerry", "Blue", 40)

r2.introduce_self()
```

I tried to check if there were any indentation errors but they were all fine, the code is supposed to have an output that says "my name is Jerry". But it still had an attribute error unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because your indentation having issue. `introduce_self` should be a method for `Robot`, so it should be having the same indent as `__init__` of `Robot` class.

Try the below code

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, rname, rcolor, rweight):
        self.name = rname
        self.color = rcolor
        self.weight = rweight
    
    def introduce_self(self):
        print("my name is " + self.name)


r1 = Robot("Tom", "Red", 30)
r2 = Robot("Jerry", "Blue", 40)

r2.introduce_self()
```

Comment: How would I change the code if i wanted the output to be "my name is jerry, my favorite color is blue, and my weight is 40 kilograms"?

Comment: Just change the print to (f"my name is {self.name}, my favourite color is {self.rcolor}, my weight is {self.rweight} kilograms")

Comment: for some reason it had an error of AttributeError: 'Robot' object has no attribute 'rcolor'

Comment: @mamamia123, sorry, should be self.color instead of self.rcolor, and self.rweight should be self.weight instead. Updated: f"my name is {self.name}, my favourite color is {self.color}, my weight is {self.weight} kilograms"

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the "init" spelling. not "init" has to `__init__` and you have to give some thing to `introduce_self` because function outside the class. And the code should look like this :

```
class Robot: 
  def __init__(self, rname, rcolor, rweight): 
    self.name = rname 
    self.color = rcolor 
    self.weight = rweight

def introduce_self(self): 
  print("my name is " + self.name)

r1 = Robot("Tom", "Red", 30) 
r2 = Robot("Jerry", "Blue", 40)

introduce_self(r2)
>>>my name is Jerry
```

You can also enclose your function in class and do it:

```
class Robot: 
  def __init__(self, rname, rcolor, rweight): 
    self.name = rname 
    self.color = rcolor 
    self.weight = rweight

  def introduce_self(self): 
    print("my name is " + self.name)

r1 = Robot("Tom", "Red", 30) 
r2 = Robot("Jerry", "Blue", 40)

r2.introduce_self()
>>>my name is Jerry
```